# Is a holomorph of a group unique?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, semidirect-product, holomorph

Suppose $G$ is a group. Then, a holomorph of $G$ is defined as a outer semidirect product ${\rm Hol}(G) = G \rtimes_{\phi} {\rm Aut}(G)$.
Since an outer semidirect product depends on a automorphism $\phi \in {\rm Aut}G$, I thought it cannot be determined uniquely.
However, I see the Klein four-group is given by
\begin{align}
{\rm Hol}(C_8) = C_8 \rtimes (C_2 \times C_2)
\end{align}
with its presentation being
\begin{align}
\langle a, b, c \mid a^8 = b^2 = c^2 =e , b^{-1}ab = a^{-1}, c^{-1}a{c} = a^5\rangle.
\end{align}

I don't understand well but, does this mean that we fixed $\phi$ by denoting the explicit presentation?

In this case, $\phi$ is set as a conjugacy, but still the result power of $a$ e.g. $b^{-1}ab = a^{-1}$ is dependent on choice, I think. Is my comprehension correct?

If so, it would be great if you could show an concrete example showing non-uniqueness of a holomorph.

Comment: @LeeMosher Actually, yes. My original question means if we denote just ${\rm Hol}(G)$, is it determined regardless of a specific choice of $\phi$?

Comment: An "outer" semidirect product $G\rtimes_\phi A$ is constructed using a homomorphism $\phi:A\to {\rm Aut}(G)$. In the case of the holomorph, $A={\rm Aut}(G)$ and $\phi$ is the identity map. There isn't a "choice" of $\phi$ in this definition, and it doesn't make sense to say $\phi$ is an element of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ anyway.

Comment: What is the role of $\phi$? Ordinarily the [homolorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Holomorph_of_a_group) $G \rtimes \text{Aut}(G)$ is defined without any additional parameter in the form an element $\phi \in \text{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: Technically, a different semidirect product exists for each $\phi \in \operatorname{End}(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$, but only the one with $\phi=id_{\operatorname{Aut}(G)}$ is called the "holomorph".

Comment: Thank you. Then in the above example, what determines the result of conjugacy $b^{-1} a b$ and $c^{-1} a c$? I thought if this is a trivial mapping i.e. $b^{-1} a b = a$, still this is an automorphism, but the result group is not the Klein four group. I'm sorry for being confused.

Comment: @runway44 I understood that in this case $\phi = {\rm id}_{{\rm Aut}(G)}$, then the holomorph is just a direct product $G \times {\rm Aut}(G)$?

Comment: Sorry, the result of power is dependent of a choice of a generator $b$ of an automorphism group but it is irrelevant to the result holomorph, is it correct?

Comment: No, $\phi={\rm id}_{{\rm Aut}(G)}$ does not imply $G\rtimes_\phi{\rm Aut}(G)=G\times{\rm Aut}(G)$. If you pick the trivial endomorphism $\psi:{\rm Aut}(G)\to{\rm Aut}(G)$ then $G\rtimes_\psi{\rm Aut}(G)=G\times{\rm Aut}(G)$, which is probably what you're confusing it with, but that's not the holomorph.

Comment: In the case of $\Bbb Z_8$ written multiplicatively as $\langle a\rangle$, the automorphism group is generated by two elements, $b(x)=x^{-1}$ and $c(x)=x^5$ (these are not the only pair of generators, we just picked these arbitrarily). The Klein-4 group is $\langle a,b\rangle$. Then within the holomorph, for $x\in\langle a\rangle$ the conjugate $bxb^{-1}$ simplifies to $b(x)$ and $cxc^{-1}$ simplifies to $c(x)$; that's how semidirect products work.

Comment: @runway44 ${\rm id}_{{\rm Aut}(G)}$ does not mean the "trivial" endomorphism?
I thought "trivial" $\Psi$ means $\Psi(k) = k ~ (k \in {\rm Aut(G)}$ but it is ${\rm id}_{{\rm Aut}(G)}$.

Comment: By trivial endomorphism $\psi:{\rm Aut}(G)\to{\rm Aut}(G)$ I mean $\psi(\alpha)={\rm id}_G$ for all $\alpha\in{\rm Aut}(G)$, where ${\rm id}_G$ is the identity function on $G$ and the trivial element of the ${\rm Aut}(G)$. In general, for any group $A$, the trivial endomorphism is the one that sends all elements of $A$ to the identity element of $A$. It is true that for $A={\rm Aut}(G)$ and $\psi$ the trivial endomorphism, the semidirect product $G\rtimes_\psi A$ is just the direct product $G\times A$, but this is not so for the holomorph $G\rtimes_\phi A$ (and $\phi={\rm id}_{{\rm Aut}(G)}$).

Comment: Now I understood. Thank you for your kind answer!